# Изменение фона окна

Tags: c++

Как изменить фон окна в `CImgDisplay` из библиотеки `CImg.h`?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью метода `fill()` класса `CImg`:

```
CImg<unsigned char> visu(500,400,1,3,0);
CImgDisplay draw_disp(visu,"Intensity profile");
while (!draw_disp.is_closed()) {
   visu.fill(255, 0, 0); // Красный цвет
   draw_disp.wait();
   visu.fill(0, 255, 0); // Зелёный цвет
   draw_disp.wait();
   visu.fill(0, 0, 255); // Синий цвет
   draw_disp.wait();
}
```